# OpenSSL Missing Ciphers? SSL connection with dog.ceo

Tags: c, encryption, openssl

I am attempting to create an ssl connection using openssl that I compiled myself. Everything works fine but I am struggling to create a connection with endpoint `https://dog.ceo/`.

I've compiled `openssl-1.0.2l` to use in a c program. There are some endpoints I can't seem to connect to because I don't have any matching ciphers. I do not explicitly remove ciphers in the configure phase of my build using `no-<cipher>` so I expect to have everything.

Here is my cipher list:

```
$ ./apps/openssl ciphers
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:SRP-DSS-AES-256-CBC-SHA:SRP-RSA-AES-256-CBC-SHA:SRP-AES-256-CBC-SHA:DH-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA256:DH-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DH-DSS-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DH-RSA-AES256-SHA:DH-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA:DHE-DSS-CAMELLIA256-SHA:DH-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA:DH-DSS-CAMELLIA256-SHA:ECDH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES256-SHA256:AES256-SHA:CAMELLIA256-SHA:PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:SRP-DSS-AES-128-CBC-SHA:SRP-RSA-AES-128-CBC-SHA:SRP-AES-128-CBC-SHA:DH-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DH-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DH-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DH-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA:DH-RSA-AES128-SHA:DH-DSS-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-SEED-SHA:DHE-DSS-SEED-SHA:DH-RSA-SEED-SHA:DH-DSS-SEED-SHA:DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA:DHE-DSS-CAMELLIA128-SHA:DH-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA:DH-DSS-CAMELLIA128-SHA:ECDH-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES128-SHA:SEED-SHA:CAMELLIA128-SHA:IDEA-CBC-SHA:PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-RC4-SHA:ECDH-RSA-RC4-SHA:ECDH-ECDSA-RC4-SHA:RC4-SHA:RC4-MD5:PSK-RC4-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:SRP-DSS-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA:SRP-RSA-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA:SRP-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:DH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:DH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDH-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:PSK-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA
```

When I try to connect to the endpoint `https://dog.ceo/` I cannot negotiate an SSL connection. I suspect because no ciphers match.

```
$ ./apps/openssl s_client -connect dog.ceo:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
139886937056944:error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s23_clnt.c:772:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 307 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1628969161
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

So I went to [ssllabs.com](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=dog.ceo&s=104.21.40.172&latest) to check what this endpoint supports. Because I only have TLS1.1 & TLS1.2 I am looking at matching at least one of those ciphers.

```
# TLS 1.2 (suites in server-preferred order)
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02b)   ECDH x25519 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS 128
OLD_TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (0xcc14)   ECDH x25519 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS   256P
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (0xcca9)   ECDH x25519 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS   256P
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc009)   ECDH x25519 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS   WEAK 128
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc023)   ECDH x25519 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS   WEAK  128
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc02c)   ECDH x25519 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS 256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc00a)   ECDH x25519 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS   WEAK 256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc024)   ECDH x25519 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS   WEAK  256
# TLS 1.1 (suites in server-preferred order)
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc009)   ECDH x25519 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS   WEAK 128
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc00a)   ECDH x25519 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS   WEAK 256
```

And I do see some matches on the ciphers list provided earlier

```
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA
```

Do none of these match? Why can't I connect?

Strange `nmap` doesn't list anything.

```
[astone@srv-usb-driverdev04 openssl-1.0.2l]$ nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 dog.ceo

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2021-08-14 15:31 EDT
Nmap scan report for dog.ceo (104.21.40.172)
Host is up (0.0033s latency).
Other addresses for dog.ceo (not scanned): 172.67.155.23
PORT    STATE SERVICE
443/tcp open  https
| ssl-enum-ciphers: 
|_  TLSv1.0: No supported ciphers found

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.24 seconds
```

Comment: Do you maybe have some sort of networking issue? When I run `ssl-enum-ciphers` against `dog.ceo` I get several cipher options

Comment: **This has nothing to do with ciphers.** As stated in the SSLLabs summary, "this site only works [with clients] that have SNI support". (Apparently because it's on Cloudflare.) OpenSSL 1.0.2 commandline `s_client` does not send SNI by default, but if you **add `-servername dog.ceo`** it connects successfully. (nmap 6.40 is way old, and is probably using an old openssl with the same issue. I hope you know OpenSSL 1.0.2 is 7 years old and went EOL long ago.)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thank you! I know 1.0.2 is dead, dumb cooperate legacy code.